# How to use UriTemplate Class in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

As [UriTemplate Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uritemplate?view=netframework-4.8) is not available in .NET Standard hence I am not able to use it in Xamarin.Forms.

**Problem Statement:-**

For a given dynamic URI template:

```
String template = "http://example.com/name/{name}/age/{age}";
```

There is a given hashmap collection which contains the name and age path parameter value

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
```

Expected implementation using UriTemplate:-

```
UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate(template);
uriTemplate.match(uri, parameters);
```

I am not able to implement this behaviour in Xamarin.Forms as this UriTemplate class is not available in .Net Standard. Is there any alternative to UriTemplate Class required to be used in Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: What do you want to do in Xamarin.forms? Tell us your requirement and we can give you solutions.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have updated the problem statement

Comment: I find the UriTemplate  is available in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. Then you  can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to achieve that.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I'll check, thank you!

Comment: Sure, have a try and let me know if it works.